# How to use blob-urls as xlink:href attribute of SVG image-tags

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

I need to display a simpile image inside of a `svg`-tag. The image is downloaded and accessable by a blob url like this "blob:http://localhost:4200/8e011a50-95a6-4063-baeb-e760b6fd98a2". The blob URL works on normal `img` without problems.

But in svg `image` tags it fails because of:

- SafeValue must use [property]=binding: blob:http://localhost:4200/4baf011f-a23d-45a7-9be2-3a6a9109ffda (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)

The Template looks like this:

```
....
<svg ...>
   <image [attr.xlink:href]="domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(blobstoreUrl)"></image>
   ...
</svg>
....
```

The component is constructing the blobstoreUrl itself:

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {

   blobstoreUrl: string

   constructor(public domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

   ngOnInit() {
     // do some calculation
     this.blobstoreUrl = "blob:http://localhost:4200/8e011a50-95a6-4063-baeb-e760b6fd98a2"
   }
}
```

In other posts i've found `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` should fix it, but it doesn't.

[image: error]

I guess the problem is that `[attr.xlink:href]` is attribute binding but as the error tells us I have to use `[property]=binding`. But how to fix that?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?  Running into the same issue